# C++ lambda capture - which get's captured?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, capture

So I have the expression below inside a class, following definitions:

```
std::vector<std::function<MyClass (const MyClass&)>> funcVec;
result->funcVec.push_back([=](const MyClass& child){
                return this->funcVec[i](child);
            });
```

(E.g. copy the lambda evaluation of (this) to the result instance)

The qustion is that I'm not sure which is captured by value - the whole object (this),potentially i or just the function (ths->funcVec[i])?

Any extra explanations and recommendation of why not to use this make it better, or confirmation that this is ok are more than welcome.

Comment: `this` is a pointer, so the pointer is captured, not what it points to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The things that can be captured are local automatic variables, by value or reference, and the pointer `this`, by value only. Your lambda uses `i` and `this`, so they are captured (assuming `i` is a local variable). You specified a default capture by value, `[=]`, so both are captured by value.

This is fine as long as the object `*this` still exists when the lambda is called.

Comment: Oops, they rephrased the automatic storage requirement in C++14 but it's still there. Never mind.

Comment: It is correct to say that if a pointer is captured by value, than the object is not copied (e.g. the memory is the same) but only a copy of the pointer is made. And this still holds if I capture a reference right? (Example: consider a method void dothis(MyClass& a) result->funcVec.push_back([=](const MyClass& child){
                return a.funcVec[i](child);

PS : I'm just interested that I do not copy unnecessary any memory as I'm trying to optimise something to the bone.

Comment: @belov: That's right, capturing a reference or pointer won't copy the underlying object.